# Closing a startup program programmatically in Vista/Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, vbscript, windows-vista, startup

I am looking to be able to write a script that will close an application that is included in the Windows start up. I know the common sense is why not remove it from start up, but I want it to run because the application connects my NAS. I just close it every single time because I have no use for the actual app except for the fact that it makes the connections.

So I got the bright idea that perhaps I could write a script that will also run in the startup after the app is launch that will kill/close it.

First does this sound possible? Is there a better way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a .bat file and run it during startup, after the NAS program has run. The following code will kill all instances of a process (the current code will kill notepad)

Dim WMI, KillProc
Dim processName: processName = "notepad.exe"

Set WMI = GetObject("winmgmts:\.\root\cimv2")
Set KillProc = WMI.ExecQuery("Select * from Win32_Process Where Name = '" & processName & "')

For Each Proc In KillProc
    Proc.Terminate()
Next

Answer (score 2):

Is the app mapping drives to shared folders on your NAS?  If so, then you could remove it from the Startup folder and either:

- use Explorer's "Map Network Drive" feature
- write a BAT file to run on Startup that does a NET USE to map
- write some VBScript :), using WScript.Network.MapNetworkDrive

Comment: @Bullines....thanks. As far as I know no. I added the app to the start up because the drives will not show up until you run this app. I tried adding a network password (UN and pwd I have for the drives, and mapping the drives myself, but on start up I get an error "Windows could not reconnect some of the drives"). So I thought fine, I will add the app to start up and just close it myself after start up. This works fine, but as I stated above, I was wondering if there was a way to write some script to handle this for me....like opening the app, then closing it just to automate the connection...

Comment: ...as I said I am a beginner...could you please provide a resource or example of the above solution? It is very much appreciated!